# How to append record to a database using DBI

Tags: mysql, r

I have table called "cars" in my database. As I have new records now and then I would like to add these to my database.

I can loop through my dataframe and push each one into the database but I dont think that the most efficient way. Can anybody tell me if there's a kind of append function for DBI? Can seem to find it in the manual. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `dbWriteTable(conn, name, value, append = TRUE)`